# Installing software on Windows 7 very slow

Tags: windows-7, performance

Since a few days, any software installation on my Windows 7 computer is very slow. This is on a Windows 7 64bit setup of just a few weeks old (new computer).

I've waited for over an hour for VirtualBox to install. Same for AVG AntiVirus and some other programs. Cancelling the installation equally takes a very long time. Effectively, I've had to kill the installation processes.

Process Explorer doesn't show any significant activity of any kind and everything else still seems to be working fine and fast. Any ideas of what might be wrong?

Comment: Is there a bunch of "bloat-ware" running in the background consuming resources? Have you contacted the manufacture? If this PC is only weeks old, it is under warranty. What diagnostics have you tried? If you want specific help, you are going to need to give more details about the PC, like brand and model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had much the same issue after reinstalling Win7 64bit on my SSD C Drive, though the C drive behaved fine. Trying to install programs, copy or delete large files to/from a partition on my existing D drive (a SATA HDD) took forever (hours) or hung as you describe.  This partition had the remnants of old installs such as bckups of 'My documents' together with the programs that ran from the last install of Windows (which had become very unstable). In safe mode transfers to and from this partition to an external HDD happened at normal speed however and chkdsk revealed no errors.
The only cure I could find (as a non-techie) was to delete the D partition, re-create and re-format.  Now everything installs/deletes as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a hard drive read-write issue. Try running some test on your hard-drive. Even if the PC is new, bad partitioning may be the cause.

Comment: It's a brand spanking new Samsung EVO 840 SSD with only one partition, so it would be a bit surprising. What is a good tool to use for testing SSD's?

Comment: @Martijn SSDs were rushed to the market, and so unlike hard drives they are notorious for needing firmware updates to resolve performance issues. :( . You could try using HD Tune Pro 15 day trial for read speed/read access time testing, but you won't be able to test write speed/write access times unless you have a spare empty partition. You can shrink usually shrink an existing partition, but this puts all data on the drive (including the OS) at risk of permenant loss if the shrink fails.

Answer (score -1):

OK, there is a bug sometimes on some computer with the hard drive controller and windows

THIS IS SOMETHING YOU CAN TRY - IT MIGHT AND IT MIGHT NOT FIX YOUR PROBLEM

For some reason Windows screws up the DMA setting on the computer, it's supposed to read the settings from the bios, but you know windows, sometimes it does it's own thing...

Sometimes this false information forces a windows machine to work in slow motion, and you could scan you PC for malware and never find anything... but this is the fix...

TRY THIS

DO A SYSTEM RESTORE SAVE FIRST JUST INCASE

Go to the device manager and delete (or remove) all sata, ide and usb storage and hard drive controllers, THEN REBOOT YOUR MACHINE

This will force windows to reload all the device drives and restore all the hard drive default settings

WARNING: THIS WILL RESET ALL YOUR DRIVE ANS USB SETTINGS TO DEFAULT, IF YOU CHANED THE DRIVE BUFFER OR DRIVE LETTER SETTINGS YOU WILL HAVE TO DO IT AGAIN

Let me know if this helps